# Is it possible to use various variables as a replacement entry in the string map of the tcl/tk?

Tags: string, dictionary, variables, tcl

I want to insert a variable with 'word' entry to be override within 'string map'. We usually do this:

```
# Input variable
set str "Is First Name"

# Result new strig 
puts [string map -nocase { {First Name} {Last Name} } $str]
```

what I need is to replace it through a second variable. For instance:

```
set replace "Last Name"

puts [string map -nocase { {First Name} $replace } $str]
```

I have the following output:

[image]

Before i asked, i did research, but I didn't find anything of the sort. I even tried to adapt other examples but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember [Rule 6](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M10): no substitution is done inside braces. So you have to build the list some other way that does allow for variable substitution, like using `list`:

```
string map -nocase [list {First Name} $replace] $str
```

You could also use [`regsub`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/regsub.htm) instead of `string map`:

```
regsub -all -nocase {***=First Name} $str $replace
```

(The leading `***=` in the regular expression means it's treated as an exact string and RE metacharacters lose their normal meaning)